# How to write a query to return list of all ids passed as input, true or false if record exist in table for given list of ids in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to pass a list of ids as input, the MySQL query should return all those passed ids along with status as true if that id is found in table, false if not exist

example: select id, status from table_a where id in (listOfIds);

table_A has the following data

```
id

1
4
5
6
7 etc
```

output :     for example if list of Ids passed as inputs are 1,2,3,4

```
           id        status 
        =========================
            1       true
            2       false 
            3       false
            4       true
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: mysql version 5.7.29

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` to return the ids that you want to search and left join to the table:

```
select 
  u.id, 
  case when t.id is null then 'false' else 'true' end `status`
from (select 1 id union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4) u
left join tablename t
on t.id = u.id
order by u.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f072bdc7d5347de2dfaa631171fd1503).
Results:

```
> id | status
> -: | :-----
>  1 | true  
>  2 | false 
>  3 | false 
>  4 | true
```

Comment: But what if list is dynamic and table may contain more data

Comment: *...table may contain more data* is not relevant. In the results you don't want the ids of the table, only the ids of the list. *...if list is dynamic* you will have to return the list as a query so you can join it to the table.

Comment: "if list is dynamic you will have to return the list as a query so you can join it to the table" ,but this not possible by the time I execute this query I will have only list of ids obtained from an external source

Comment: If *it is not possible* then why do you have in your question as an example: `...in (1,2,3,4)`? How would you construct this list if *it is not possible*? The code in my answer is about the question as you posted it where you don't mention anything about dynamic list.